# Sum data for spesific row with filter from other row

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, devexpress

I have grid with data being input.

```
Item  Price   Type
A     1000    1
B     1000    2
C     2000    2
D     3000    3
```

I want sum(price) with type that has value "2".

```
try
{
    foreach (int i in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
    {
        DataRow newRow = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);

        if (newRow["NOMINAL"] is DBNull) { newRow["NOMINAL"] = 0; }

        if (e.Column.FieldName == "IDISJ")
        {
            if (verifikasiNamaISJ(IDisj, e.RowHandle) == true)
            {
                TampilkanPesan.Error("Nama Item Sudah Ada!");
                newRow["IDISJ"] = 0;
                return;
            }

            newRow["IDISJ"] = IDisj;

            gridView1.FocusedColumn = colNominal;
            gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = e.RowHandle;

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                gridView1.ShowEditor();
            });

            cariDataItem(Convert.ToInt64(Global.PeriksaDBNullAngka(newRow["IDISJ"])));

            newRow["NAMAISJ"] = NamaISJ;
            newRow["NAMAJENISISJ"] = Jenis;
            newRow["NOMINAL"] = 0;
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable()
        >>>> txtTotalPotongan.EditValue = Convert.ToString(dt.Compute("SUM(NOMINAL)", "NAMAJENISISJ = 'Pemotongan'"));
        >>>> txtTotalDiterima.EditValue = Convert.ToString(dt.Compute("SUM(NOMINAL)", "NAMAJENISISJ = 'Pendapatan'"));
    }
}
catch (FbException ex)
{
    TampilkanPesan.Error(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

the line with >>>> was my work, but I have no idea how to do it. I guess I'm doing it wrong, since I put Datatable there. It's not data yet, still value of row.

But I don't know how to sum with filter, if not using filter I can do it. Please help me the right line of code for it.

I put this on `gridview1_cellvaluechanged` for every time something changes, it will update the value on textbox as well.

Comment: Your question is not really related to Firebird, as you seem to do the querying on the datatable.

Comment: in Firebird terms the solution would be `SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM name-of-table WHERE TYPE=2` but it seems your questions has nothing with Firebird indeed

Comment: ah im so sorry, i though making tag firebird because im using firebird as database for my program. i've delete it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your datable to a list using `System.Data.DataSetExtensions;` and use Linq to filter and find the sum you are looking for.

```
var sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x=> (int)x["Type"] == 2).Sum(x => (int)x["Price"]);
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dqrF3b) you can find a working example using your Items table.

Comment: sorry if im really slow to understand Sakjs, im using devexpress making grid table.

that data on grid was input manually when using program.
im making textbox to show SUM like ive said above.

im trying to get that grid data everytime he making change data.
the problem was im confuse how can i get all data on that grid into var dt.

so i can calculate it using ur answer. i try `var dt = gridview1.DataSource(); / new DataTable(gridview1);` all was false.

Comment: There must be a line before the part you've posted where `gridview1.Datasource = dt;` . Capture that datatable to a list `var datasource = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();` and when you get to the part you've posted, all you have to do is update that list with the values that have been entered from the gridview and compute the sums. You are already iterating through the gridview rows that have been changed. To update the list do something like `datasource.SingleOrDefault(x => x["Item"] == "A" && x["Type"] == 1)?.Price = 1200;` to find the row needs updating and update it.

Comment: i'm so sorry if im still not understand sakis, where is that dt come from? i think it's almost there, just still don't get it. it might help abit, [here] (http://s913.photobucket.com/user/ircinka/media/az_zpsmxf6jtnm.png.html) is my form picture. <br/> there is textbox Potongan and diterima, i want to get the data i've been input in that grid and calculate it right away based on filter like i've said and put in that textbox. i'm so sorry if i'm not smart to understand it.

Comment: that `gridview1` must have somewhere in your code a databinding assignment to its `Datasource` property. Find the line where `gridview1.DataSource = ` assigns something to the DataSource property of  the gridview. Capture that something before you bind it to gridview and use it in the part of the code that you've posted here as explained in my previous comment. That something might be a DataTable or something else that is assignable to DataSource property.